# Transparent pixels

Tags: c#, wpf, image, bitmapimage

I have WPF project. There is `StackPanel` and two `Image` elements on it. I want to crop (with Intelligence Scissors algorithm) first image and overlay it over the second. How can I do that? I tried to change alpha channel of every pixel, but it didn't work. Looks like it's not possible.

Comment: `StackPanel` doesn't sound like the best choice if you want to overlay the 2 images - try `Canvas`instead and set the Zindex property

Comment: I am not sure it will work. I need only part of the first image. So, I suppose it should depend on pixels settings.

Comment: If you can add some code with what you have tried we might be able to help more...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this , except that the path;s Data needs to set throw code when your done connecting the all the dots .

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Geometry x:Key="pathToCropImageBy">M 32.5,0.499977L 192.5,0.499977L 192.5,160.5L 160.5,128.5L 160.5,32.5L 64.5,32.5L 32.5,0.499977 Z M 0.5,64.5001L 128.5,64.5L 128.5,192.5L 96.5,160.5L 96.5,96.5001L 32.5,96.5001L 0.5,64.5001 Z </Geometry>

    </Grid.Resources>


    <Image Source="man1-48.png">
        <Image.OpacityMask>
            <DrawingBrush Stretch="Uniform">
                <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                    <DrawingGroup>
                        <DrawingGroup.Children>
                            <GeometryDrawing Brush="White" Geometry="{StaticResource pathToCropImageBy}">                                   
                            </GeometryDrawing>
                        </DrawingGroup.Children>
                    </DrawingGroup>
                </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
            </DrawingBrush>
        </Image.OpacityMask>
    </Image>                            
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Grid>
      <Image ... your first pic />
      <Image Opacity="0.5" ... your second pic />
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

`Grid` helps you to overlay elements on each other. `Opacity` let's you control the opacity of second picture, so you can blend it with first one.